# Python data related error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dataframe, object

I am trying to automate a process for my job. I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Number of UPN's: 
  File "C:/Users/Ultrarev/Desktop/Emeran-Parser/Eme_Parser.py", line 63, in <module>
74
    if rowExcel[0] == kPN[i]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
```

As an error and though I am new to Python I do not know how to approach this with out staring at the screen. I want to make a dictionary of product numbers to cars of interest(i.e. the car(s) the parts can fit into) object. That object will in turn generate respective cars that can fit that particular part.

```
import csv
import collections
import sys

from Car_of_Interest import Car_of_Interest


def main ():

    data = csv.open(r"C:\Users\Ultrarev\Desktop\Duplicator-fier\Book1.csv")
    data = csv.reader(data)

    print("Data: (testing)")

def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

with open(r'C:\Users\Ultrarev\Desktop\Duplicator-fier\Book1.csv', newline = '') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rowExcel = []
    kPN = []
    car_info = []
    UPN = ()
    cUPN = []
    CARS = {}
    #UPN_len = len(UPN)
    for row in data:
        open(r'C:\Users\Ultrarev\Desktop\Duplicator-fier\Book1.csv')
        rowExcel.append(row)

        car_info.append(row[2])
        car_info.append(row[3])
        car_info.append(row[4])

        #print('-> '.join(row))
    for row in rowExcel:
        kPN.append(row[0])

# Convert to string.
list1 = kPN
str1 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list1)

#Remove Duplicates in kPN.
UPN = f7(kPN)


l = UPN.__sizeof__()

print("kPN: ")
print(kPN)
print("Data: ")
print(data)
print("UPN: ")
print(UPN)
print("Major Car Information of File to be Parsed into HTML: ")
print(rowExcel)
print("Number of UPN's: ")
print(len(UPN))

for i in kPN:
    for x in rowExcel:
        if rowExcel[0] == kPN[i]:
           #Create Dictionary - UPN:[car...n]
           #Make car objects.
           Car_of_Interest(rowExcel[2], rowExcel[3], rowExcel[4])

#    cars_I
#     ^   
#     |
#UPN:[Car_of_Interest...n]
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaVbU.png)

Comment: Apparently `i` is a String. What are you wanting `kPN[i]` to do in that case? Did you mean to use `enumerate`?

Comment: You can't index a list by a string -- only an integer or a slice. Do you want to check if the list contains the string?

Comment: I want to check if the list KPN is equal to the first element of the multidimensional list rowExcel. As in is KPN == all of the first elements in rowExcel.... do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in kPN:
    for x in rowExcel:
        if rowExcel[0] == kPN[i]:
```

I am guessing in the above you want `i` not `kPN[i]`

you are already getting the value out of `kPN` with the `for i in kPN` loop.

Comment: Yes, I presume. Also rowExcel is a multidimensional list.

Answer (score 0):

kPN is a vector, if you use `for i in kPN`, each **i** is an element of kPN

Try this:

```
for i in kPN:
    for x in rowExcel:
        if rowExcel[0] == i:
```

or

```
for i in range(len(kPN)):
    for x in rowExcel:
        if rowExcel[0] == kPN[i]:
           ...
```